# Should a Question about Solr be on Stack Overflow or Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have a question about [solr](/questions/tagged/solr) which is a search server. As of right now, there is no real programming involved with it, so I would assume that it should go on Server Fault.

The problem I am finding is that there are a lot of Solr questions on Stack Overflow. I guess I am asking should I post the question at Server Fault or Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's server configuration then it belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: They can ship it over to us if it turns out to be a little too programmy. Yeah, if it's mostly config / deployment, SF is the better place.

Comment: First comment I got on my question was if I tried it on SO. Would you mind reviewing it to see where it should be? http://serverfault.com/questions/463047/not-getting-desired-results-from-solr-facets Thanks

Comment: Just note that not everything that contains the word "server" belongs on [SF].

Answer (score 2):

I'm the one who commented asking if it was tried on SO. There's definitely a lot of overlap here. Solr functions as a server, so there's administrator interest in setting it up and running, but integrating it with a specific application could be seen as more in the realm of application developers. Having read Josh's question, I could see it fitting on either site; it's not clear (to me) if the issue is a server misconfiguration or a problem with the application integration.

My suggestion that it be asked on SO was driven mostly by the idea that there are more eyes there, so an answer might be easier to come by there. On the other hand, there are more questions there, so it might get buried faster there as well.